# How do I import Imagedataset from Google Drive to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

My code for loading image dataset in colab don't work

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/artist/images/images.csv")
```

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) Google Drive to get that data. It will look something like this:

```py
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/gdrive')

    with open('/gdrive/MyDrive/kaggle/artist/images/images.csv', 'r') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Colab provides example code snippets for you to use... Insert > Code Snippets > Search: "google drive" > Select "Mounting Google Drive in your VM". Good luck!

Comment: merci c'est gentil mais malheureusement cela ne fonctionne pas

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/gdrive/MyDrive/kaggle/artist/images/images.csv'

Comment: Does that file actually exist in Google Drive for that 'kaggle' account? I'm not familiar with kaggle so I don't know what that is... but maybe the error is correct if that file doesn't exist or isn't accessible to you.

Comment: I should have asked in my previous comment... what's the source of your original path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/artist/images/images.csv"? Maybe I can find more information from that source.

Comment: LE fichier data est totalement telechargé directement de kaggle par une procedure usuelle (via le cloud) pui enregistré sur mon drive, cela fonctionne bien habituellement, mais je n'avais jamais téléchargé de dataset avec images. C'est pourquoi je ne comprends pas pkoi ca bug

Comment: I understand. Update your notebook to add this code snippet after the mount code '%ls /gdrive/MyDrive/'. Does it show a directory named kaggle?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the issue is remaining

Comment: Can you Edit your original post with additional information... including a screenshot of the output after you mount Google Drive and then do a ls? I'm happy to continue *trying* to assist, but I need more information.